# Shortest path with certain points

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I have a warehouse that has many storage yards. I have an order. It has items list and I have to collect them from storage yards. Storage yards are not equal each other. Their length are different from others. I have CAD drawing of the warehouse. I convert it meaningfully for spatial queries with MapInfo and post it to PostgreSQL.

[image: this is my warehouse model]
[image: this is my mapinfo model]

I use a point to get location of storage yards and connect them each other with lines.

I need to get shortest path between warehouse enter gate and exit gate when I collect the items from storage yards.

Now here is my doubts,

- Should I use which version of PostgreSQL and PostGIS?
- When I research TSP I see various algorithm exists. Should I use which technique?
- How can I compare these technique each other?
- Should I import my points and lines to PostgreSQL as x,y coordinate as each one is one column or both are in one column?
- What should I give cost for each line? Should it be 1 for every line?

Comment: You are talking about pgRouting, correct? Generally speaking, unless you have a good reason otherwise, use the latest version of Postgis/Postgres, as there are always new features being added. pgRouting is actually an addon, so the version doesn't matter that much.

Comment: Due to the fact that you are working with a small plan, I would simply arrange your data in the form of sets of lines that make up your route options ...